# Any ways to make a GUI application fullscreen in EXWM?

Tags: exwm, x-window

I'm used to i3wm, as well as a couple other WM, but i noticed that, as far as i know, there isn't any function or keybinding existing in EXWM (by default) to make a GUI application fullscreen (which i3wm and other support).

Example: For instance, using i3wm, one can use the `Super`+`f` key combination (Super being the Windows keys on most keyboards) to force a GUI application/windows fullscreen.

Just curious if this is already a thing or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the answer was already in the docs on [github](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/wiki#layout-modes).

`We regard fullscreen as a third layout mode here. An X window in either tiling or floating mode can be made fullscreen explicitly by invoking C-c C-f.`